# Gray SCREEN NETBEANS! Instale un plugin en netbeans y se me daño MAC

Tags: netbeans, macos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
TENGO LA SOLUCION PERO NO SE COMO PUEDO PUBLICAR UNA SOLUCION, ASI QUE REALICE LA PREGUNTA, ME TOMO 1 DIA ENTERO SOLUCIONARLO, ASI QUE PARA EVITAR QUE TU EN UN FUTURO LA ESTES PASANDO MAL, SUBO LA SOLUCION RESPONDIENDOLA A LA PREGUNTA, SALUDOS Y SUERTE!
//
I HAVE THE SOLUTION BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW I CAN PUBLISH A SOLUTION, SO I ASKED THE QUESTION, IT TOOK ME A WHOLE DAY TO SOLVE IT, SO TO AVOID YOU FROM HAVING A BAD TIME IN THE FUTURE, I UPLOAD THE SOLUTION ANSWERING THE QUESTION, GREETINGS AND GOOD LUCK !

Comment: Revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor has el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION !! MAC
hermano tengo la solución, desinstala el netbeans, eliminando las carpetas al basurero, luego vas al disco duro Macintosh HD, click derecho y abrir en terminal y ahí ejecutas los siguientes comandos:

COMANDS TERMINAL

rm -rf ~/.netbeans

rm rf~/Library/Application\Support/NetBeans

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/NetBeans

rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/org.netbeans*

Luego que ejercitar los comandos no te dará respuesta el terminal, o sea no te mostrara algo como "removido con éxito" simplemente los pones y ya, también ponlos en el terminal normal sin abrirlo en Macintosh HD.
instalas de nuevo la ultima versión o la versión que tenias dañada y listo se quita, si tienes dudas me dices respondo rápido

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos evitar realizar publicaciones repetidas en el sitio. Revisa [answer]